# Creating ::: Importing data in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

I am quite quite new to SQL server.  I tried to create a database in SQL Server Management Studio Express.  It has created the database but I did not find Import option in the menu when I right-clocked my Database,  It should have been in Tasks, but it is not there.  I want to use this databse in vb.net application.

1) Am I using the right tool to create the Access Database?
2) Where does this tool save the database?

Thanks
Furqan

Comment: Do you want to create sql database or access database(regarding your first question)?

Comment: Your question is tagged sql-server and you ask about the tool to create an Access database? do you mean MS Access?

Comment: I am sorry, I mis-typed the word.  I want to create SQL database

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are using the correct tool to create a db.

I don't have the express version, but [try this link.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/546f4407-0aa4-4b04-96f3-e6f0ba39a9d1/) Hope it helps.

Make sure you set the db permissions correctly too. So others can access the db.

Comment: Sorry missed part two - when you create new db - scroll the general tab right and you will see the filepath where the db is stored.

Comment: How can I import data from my Access Database to SQL Server Database?

Comment: I think there's a data import wizard? have a look here: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-access.aspx